# Starting with SQL Server 2017, there will be no more Service Packs (only Cumulative Updates). Won't CUs get large?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

My understanding is that Cumulative Updates contain *every* update that rolled out before it.  This means that if you are running CU2, but CU6 is available, you can just install CU6 and get all of the updates from CU3, CU4, CU5, and CU6.

With this new model, however, won't CU size grow enormous?  SQL Server versions last for around a decade, so maybe by CU100 the size would be unmanagable?

Could I get general thoughts on this concern?  I'm wondering if maybe just my understanding of the new system is wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a question for a website about programming. You'd be better off asking on the msdb forums about this, or perhaps DBA (but this is really off topic for there too).

Comment: You're asking about a 2-year old version. You can just check the sizes of the patches released in the past 2 years

Comment: This model isn't new at all. All cumulative updates have always included every update from previous CUs. The only difference is that in older versions, this only went back as far as the last service pack -- but for SQL Server 2014 alone there were *18* CUs for SP2, while 2017 has racked up 17 CUs so far over its entire liftetime, with 2019 just having been released. The practical implications are therefore negligible -- there's almost certainly not going to be a CU100, as support will be reduced to security hotfixes before it can get that far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 2017 came out two years ago, so you can just check the file sizes. The answer is no, in fact they are smaller than the old model.

If you [check the list of CUs](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=sql%20server%202017) you'll see they grew from 250MB for CU1 to 520MB for CU17.

If you check the list of [SQL Server 2016 downloads](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=sql%20server%202016) SP1 which came out in 2016 was 550MB and SP2 which came out in 2018 was 774MB. The 2016 CUs are at least 500MB. Even the first SP1 CUs were at least 400MB.

Comment: Thanks this helped: CUs will maybe grow to a few GB in size (toward the end of life of a version of SQL Server) but that is not a big deal.  Thanks again!